# Maximum no of overlaps of all time intervals

Tags: algorithm

Given a set of time intervals , how to find the find the maximum no of overlaps . Is there any algorithm which solves the given problem with time complexity O(n log n ) or O(n)??

example : (6:00-9:30),(9:00-12:30),(10:00-10:30), (12:00-14:30), (11:00-13:30).The answer is 3

Comment: It depends. If an item overlaps two different sets is it considered one overlap or two overlaps? Also, is (12:14:30) correct? Is it a timestamp? It is just inconsistent given the other sets.

Comment: Aren't there 4 time overlaps?  Assuming (12:14:30) is supposed to be (12:00-14:30)

Comment: @Firo thats a typo , see the edited version .

Comment: I count 4 too... does (10:00-10:30) not count as an overlap since both ends are inside the other set (9:00-12:30)? -also, you didn't answer my first question.

Comment: Yes, there are algorithms that solve this problem - it is solved by a simple greedy algorithm http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activity_selection_problem

Comment: What does "maximum no of overlaps" mean, exactly?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum . The link given deals with " maximum number of activities that can be performed by a single person". This is irrelevant to the question I posted

Comment: @user2601967 a user can only participate in activities that do not have overlapping time slots. do you see the connection now?

Comment: @user2601967 Maybe if you actually answer the questions asked in the comments, we will be able to understand what you're trying to do and you won't get irrelevant responses.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18364752/maximum-working-time-for-a-set-of-intervals/18364913#18364913

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaun Greedy algorithms would not work there would always be suboptimum solutions in this data set...

Comment: I *think* that "maximum overlaps" means "maximum events happening at once", which equates to "what's the minimum number of people to assign these tasks to". It's the only way I see a correct answer of 3(from 12:00 to 12:30), and works with gbtimmon's answer.

Comment: @Geobits i don't know whether your interpretation of question is correct or not . But the answer is 3

Comment: @user2601967 You don't know what your own question means?

Comment: **You don't know?** Voting to close.

Comment: Probably a homework problem that @user2601967 just didn't understand.

Comment: I doubt the way one see  this problem in this way "what's the minimum number of people to assign these tasks to".

Comment: @Firo thats not Home work problem  btw

Comment: @user2601967 It doesn't really matter whether it's homework or not. The problem is that you don't even understand what you're asking. It looks obviously copy/pasted from somewhere else, with absolutely no thought or effort put into it on your part. Even if a correct answer is given, you can't recognize it's correct, only that it gives the output you desire for that specific input. With no way of explaining it, you give no way to *correctly* answer it. *That's* why it gets a close vote from me, not because "it's homework". I don't care if it is, as long as you show some effort.

Answer (score 18):

Sort the values using quick sort -- `O(nlogn)` time.

```
 6:00(+)
 9:30(-)
 9:00(+)
12:30(-)
10:00(+)
10:30(-)
12:14:30(Dude wut?) --> Im going to assume you meant 12:00(+) ,14:30(-)
11:00(+)
13:30(-)
```

Becomes

```
 6:00(+)
 9:00(+)
 9:30(-)
10:00(+)
10:30(-)
11:00(+)
12:00(+)
12:30(-)
13:30(-)
14:30(-)
```

Iterate through the list incrementing for every plus and decrementing for every minus, record the max value found. This takes `O(n)` time

Total time `O(nlogn + n) = O(nlogn)`